# Prestashop installation issue

Tags: installation, prestashop

i have problem with installation prestashop on webhosting server (paid) ... 
everything goes ok until 56% demo data

I tried install prestashop on localhost(computer) and everything work perfectly but on webhosting not

Does anybody know where is problem ??

Comment: Did you checked the error log of the web server? What version of PrestaShop are you trying to install?

Answer (score 0):

Shared server has some limitations with PHP configuration first of all you need to figure out which problems or PHP configurations prevent your installation. If you are no a technical/developer then just do this:

1. Install Prestashop on your localhost means on your local computer in XAMMP/WAMP/MAMP/LAMP whatever you find convinient for you
2. Now you should move this local installation to your live web server, to do this follow the below steps:

   2.1. Make a zip of your installation and upload it using your cPanel/FTP and extract it on your server.

   2.2. Export your local database as SQL dump and import it on your live server database,to do this you need to create database on your server first.

   2.3. Now, open /config/**settings.inc.php** and change the values of _DB_NAME_ , _DB_SERVER_ , _DB_USER_ , and _DB_PASSWD_ according to your server database.

   2.4. This on is the most important point. Open your databse and go to **ps_shop_url** table and change value of two fields:
       (1) domain / domain_ssl = www.yourdomain.com
       (2) Physical_uri = /

Now, all is set, but wait before accessing your site go to dashboard first and from **PREFERENCES -> SEO & URL** turn Friendly URL OFF and turn it ON again. This will rgerate your .htaccess file again
If you follow this steps you will get your Prestashop installed without any issues. Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to increase PHP execution time in PHP.ini file, it's better to install Prestashop in local system and later migrate to the live server.

After exporting database from local and importing to the live server.
Change **ps_shop_url table values**, **ps_configuration** in the **live database** to your live domain.

Access and change "**app/config/parameters.php**" values.

**Delete .htaccess** in your **root directory**.

**Access** your **admin panel**.
**Check** your **left side dashboard** menu for "**configure**" title.

**Shop Parameters->Traffic & SEO->**
If values are wrong under "**SET SHOP URL**", and change it.
Click **save** button even if you have not changed anything, **it will generate new .htaccess**